# Error Network is unreachable for WIFI

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

For some unknown reason, WIFI stopped working (Internet via cable - works properly), when pinging - it gives the following ping error: connect: Network is unreachable.
I'm new to Ubuntu, can anyone tell me how to fix the problem with WIFI?
Thanks!

ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:a9:38:1d:d4:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 192.168.1.239/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 39442sec preferred_lft 39442sec
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672::59e/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:3fc:7130:e5f9:a505/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 601044sec preferred_lft 82117sec
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:c03:83e2:e150:1b96/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9325:c095:1a5f:83f0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:94:02:41:f8:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672::e6a/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:3a8f:45da:f548:2f79/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 598087sec preferred_lft 79401sec
    inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:fb15:a45:d44c:d034/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7ae7:8fc3:e63e:954d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-21b84ad2dbf1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b8:cc:49:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.96.1/20 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global br-21b84ad2dbf1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-2ecc8b3431a7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c5:b4:59:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-2ecc8b3431a7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-7fcbee73d3c7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:37:ff:14:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.0.1/16 brd 172.23.255.255 scope global br-7fcbee73d3c7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-0ca126777416: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:72:ed:ae:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.26.0.1/16 brd 172.26.255.255 scope global br-0ca126777416
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br-711ba232865f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b0:d5:c7:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.29.0.1/16 brd 172.29.255.255 scope global br-711ba232865f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-cfb23b24456d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:29:c4:92:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-cfb23b24456d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6c:a6:ee:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: br-4cadc3ef8e58: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f4:d0:15:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.208.1/20 brd 192.168.223.255 scope global br-4cadc3ef8e58
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br-6b88c7c22933: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:55:e2:01:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-6b88c7c22933
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: br-890f7e52c33d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:08:45:82:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-890f7e52c33d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: br-c7c9cbb19c25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:db:44:00:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.27.0.1/16 brd 172.27.255.255 scope global br-c7c9cbb19c25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: br-5845d74d52fe: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:26:d7:b2:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.0.1/16 brd 172.30.255.255 scope global br-5845d74d52fe
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: br-c7e576c9f0c2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:97:57:14:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.0.1/16 brd 172.24.255.255 scope global br-c7e576c9f0c2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: br-cf6d39507823: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:30:ed:10:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.0.1/16 brd 172.28.255.255 scope global br-cf6d39507823
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: br-ed85261cdb8f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:53:ff:fe:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.32.1/20 brd 192.168.47.255 scope global br-ed85261cdb8f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: br-f6412b786f22: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:19:ac:3a:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-f6412b786f22
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route show:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-2ecc8b3431a7 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-cfb23b24456d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-890f7e52c33d proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-f6412b786f22 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-7fcbee73d3c7 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-c7e576c9f0c2 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-6b88c7c22933 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-0ca126777416 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-c7c9cbb19c25 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 linkdown 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-cf6d39507823 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-711ba232865f proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-5845d74d52fe proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.239 metric 100 
192.168.32.0/20 dev br-ed85261cdb8f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.32.1 linkdown 
192.168.96.0/20 dev br-21b84ad2dbf1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.96.1 linkdown 
192.168.208.0/20 dev br-4cadc3ef8e58 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.208.1 linkdown
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Langate_home"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:72:63:DC:58:5D   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

br-21b84ad2dbf1  no wireless extensions.

br-2ecc8b3431a7  no wireless extensions.

br-7fcbee73d3c7  no wireless extensions.

br-0ca126777416  no wireless extensions.

br-711ba232865f  no wireless extensions.

br-cfb23b24456d  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-4cadc3ef8e58  no wireless extensions.

br-6b88c7c22933  no wireless extensions.

br-890f7e52c33d  no wireless extensions.

br-c7c9cbb19c25  no wireless extensions.

br-5845d74d52fe  no wireless extensions.

br-c7e576c9f0c2  no wireless extensions.

br-cf6d39507823  no wireless extensions.

br-ed85261cdb8f  no wireless extensions.

br-f6412b786f22  no wireless extensions.
```

nmcli:

```
eno1: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 84:A9:38:1D:D4:34, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.239/24
        route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
        route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:6faa:1db1:8c7e:1427/64
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672::59e/128
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:c03:83e2:e150:1b96/64
        inet6 fe80::9325:c095:1a5f:83f0/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::/64 metric 100
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::/48 via fe80::ee08:6bff:fe7c:afa4 metric 100
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::59e/128 metric 100

wlp4s0: connected to Langate_home
        "MEDIATEK Renoir/Cezanne GPP Bridge"
        wifi (mt7921e), C8:94:02:41:F8:27, hw, mtu 1500
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:69f0:3353:922a:e736/64
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672::e6a/128
        inet6 fdc9:3aa:7672:0:fb15:a45:d44c:d034/64
        inet6 fe80::7ae7:8fc3:e63e:954d/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::/64 metric 600
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::/48 via fe80::ee08:6bff:fe7c:afa4 metric 600
        route6 fdc9:3aa:7672::e6a/128 metric 600
```

Comment: Did this not show up anything helpfull: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+enable+wifi ?

Comment: @Luuk No, I just broke my Ethernet))

Comment: All I see is `eno1` which suggests an ethernet device.  The 169.254 suggests that your DHCP on your network is busted which handles automatic IP assignment.  Reboot your router and your computer and try again, both Ethernet and Wifi.